# separate function, error:object not found

Tags: r

I am trying to separate the first column in the attached tibble (a file is called data).

[image: data]

The code I am using looks a follows:

```
data %>% separate(
`age,unit,sex,indic_em,geo\time`,
into = c('age', 'unit', 'sex', 'indic_em', 'geo\time'),
sep = ',',
remove = F,
convert = T)
```

Yet, I am receiving this error: Error in eval_tidy(enquo(var), var_env) : 
  object 'age,unit,sex,indic_em,geo\time' not found

Any ideas what can cause the issue?
Many thanks!

Comment: Without a small reproducible example with `dput`, it is not clear.  Please check your column names

Comment: You're likely running into a problem with using \ which is an escape character in R.  Likely you'll need to escape the backlash with \\ or rename the column.

Comment: @manotheshark, please post your comment as an answer ...

Answer (score 1):

You're likely running into a problem with using `\` which is an escape character in R. Likely you'll need to either escape the backlash with `\\` or rename the column to remove the character.

Comment: You may replace “likely” with “definitely” ;-)